# How can I use a serial port to listen to if toggles are switched?

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

In my software I need to detect when an operator toggles one of two miniature toggle electric switches:

[image]

and which one.

I want to do this with as little external hardware as possible.
I was thinking that maybe I could use a USB to serial cable?

Looking at the [WaitCommEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-waitcommevent) documentation I notice that I can listen to for instance:

- EV_CTS: The CTS (clear-to-send) signal changed state.
- EV_DSR: The DSR
  (data-set-ready) signal changed state.

Looking at the DB-9 pins:

[image]

It seems that I could connect a voltage source trough the toggle 1 to pin 8 (CTS) and to ground?
Likewise it seems that I could connect a voltage source trough the toggle 2 to pin 6 (DSR) and to ground?

Will this work? Is there a better way to do this only using a USB to serial cable?

Comment: Just a hint: You'd have to make damn sure the USB/UART Cable supports the handshake lines you are trying to use. From my experience in the field, not all do. Also, I guess this question is better suited for [electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The drive strength of UART signals from a PC is typically so-so and poorly documented. Furthermore you have to consider ESD.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about hardware, not programming. It belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: instead of a USB to serial cable have you considered a USB to GPIO cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of sparing you the work of reposting to the electronics exchange:

According to [this](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/connectivity/serial-data-communications/rs232-signal-voltage-levels.php) document, setting CTS on means a voltage of at least +3V on the CTS line, relative to GND. Similarly, setting CTS off means a voltage of at least -3V on the CTS line, relative to GND. So you'd need two voltage sources, one for >+3V (GND to Serial GND) and one isolated one for <-3V (Plus to Serial GND).

DSR functions similarly, according to the document.

Also, your switch looks like an SPST. You'd need at least an SPDT for this if you want to avoid using resistors.

Comment: The output pins of the interface provide already such compatible voltages; you might want to add that.

Comment: @thebusybee: I measure 13.1 V from pin 4 (DTR) to pin 5. I guess this could be wired to trigger the events?